# Deserializing C data

Tags: python, networking, udp, deserialization

I'm receiving a struct over a network from a C server to my Python client. The protocol is UDP. I have no control over the server and it's protocols/data formats. It consists of this struct (yes, an IPv4 + port):

```
struct ip_s {
    uint8_t i1;
    uint8_t i2;
    uint8_t i3;
    uint8_t i4;
    uint16_t port; // big endian
};
```

Apart from the port which is converted to big-endian the data is sent "as-is", casted to a `(char*)`.

How can I receive this struct to a format that is processable by Python?

---

Misc info:

- Python 2.7 or 3.x
- Cross-platform
- Preferably solution using only built-in modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [struct.unpack](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/struct.html)

It will probably look something like this:

```
# socket setup

(buffer, sockaddress) = mysocket.recvfrom(6)
if len(buffer)== 6:
    i1,i2,i3,i4, port = struct.unpack('!BBBBH', buffer)
```

Comment: Yeah already found it right after asking, but I'll leave the question here for further reference.

Comment: Oh, and `"BBBBH"` should've been `"!BBBBH"` for the big-endian port.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm receiving a struct over a network

Stop right there. Don't do that. This technique introduces the following dependencies:

1. Word order: big-endian or little-endian.
2. Padding.
3. Packing.

(2) and (3) in turn depend on:

1. The compiler.
2. The compiler version.
3. The surrounding #pragmas.
4. The compiler options in effect when the C program was compiled.

That's rather a lot of dependencies. Don't do this. Define an application protocol and use it. Or use something like XDR that solves the problem for you.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't "stop right there", at least not with reading: `I have no control over the server and it's protocols/data formats.`

Comment: @nightcracker So either the server is incompetently designed, which somebody needs to get control over, or, more probably, that's just a way of describing the application protocol, and it really is a wire protocol consisting of four octets followed by a two-octet integer in network byte order.

Comment: There is no difference between your description and mine, because the implementation uses `uint8` and the likes which leaves no space for implementation. I'm really stuck with the design of the server, it's a master server for CoD4 based on [this code](http://svn.icculus.org/twilight/trunk/dpmaster/src/messages.c?revision=10433&view=markup).